# Spring boot with thymeleaf doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {


    public static void main(String args[]){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String index(){
        return "index";
    }


}
```

Also I have templates folder in resources folder and inside error.html and index.html

When I access localhost:8080/index the error is shown and not the index. What am I doing wrong? It's really the simplest possible set up and its already wrong...

Comment: do you have application.properties file ?

Comment: I dont have it, its not necessary

Comment: you should access localhost:8080/index/ (with the trailing slash) because you requested it. Or remove the method level mapping @RequestMapping("/").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `IndexController` class. In the way that you declare it you can access your page via : `http://localhost:8080/index/` but not `localhost:8080/index` url. Thats why you have class annotation `@RequestMapping` and the same annotation on your method.

The url construction is some kind of hierarchical - first spring check class annotation then your method annotation and the builded Request Mapping Handler is : `host` + `port` + `"index"`  + `"/"` .

Comment: You're right. but when I first read it, I thought you meant it was missing the "http://".